# Remove a comma from last line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove the last , from my JSON output using powershell, I'm a Linux admin, and I would use sed or awk to do that, but I wonder how I can accomplish the same task using powershell.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "{#SERVICESTATE}": "Stopped",
            "{#SERVICEDISPLAY}": "Application Experience",
            "{#SERVICENAME}": "AeLookupSvc"
        },
       {
         "{#SERVICESTATE}": "Stopped",
         "{#SERVICEDISPLAY}": "Application Layer Gateway Service",
         "{#SERVICENAME}": "ALG"
    },  <--------- This is the comma I would like to remove from my output ---->
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is that a string array, or a single multi-line string?

Comment: its a multi-line string, only the last , from last occurrence needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Using -replace with a multi-line regex:

```
$JSON_Text = 
@'
{
    "data": [
        {
            "{#SERVICESTATE}": "Stopped",
            "{#SERVICEDISPLAY}": "Application Experience",
            "{#SERVICENAME}": "AeLookupSvc"
        },
       {
         "{#SERVICESTATE}": "Stopped",
         "{#SERVICEDISPLAY}": "Application Layer Gateway Service",
         "{#SERVICENAME}": "ALG"
    },  <--------- This is the comma I would like to remove from my output ---->
]


}
'@

$JSON_Text -replace '(?ms)(.+)(},)(.+)','$1}$3' 



{
    "data": [
        {
            "{#SERVICESTATE}": "Stopped",
            "{#SERVICEDISPLAY}": "Application Experience",
            "{#SERVICENAME}": "AeLookupSvc"
        },
       {
         "{#SERVICESTATE}": "Stopped",
         "{#SERVICEDISPLAY}": "Application Layer Gateway Service",
         "{#SERVICENAME}": "ALG"
    }  <--------- This is the comma I would like to remove from my output ---->
]


}
```

That first capture is "greedy", so it'll run right past that first }, and stop at that last one.

Answer (score 0):

Load the file up with Get-Content (alias GC), start at the end and step back line by line looking for a comma, and replace it with nothing with it's found. Then output the file again.

```
$file = gc c:\temp\test.txt
for($i = $file.count;$i -ge 0;$i--){if($file[$i] -match ","){$file[$i] = $file[$i] -replace ",";break}}
$file|out-file c:\temp\test.txt -force
```

Comment: very good idea! thank you, My script is generating the output as it gets executed, do you think I should send the output to a file, then run your command to clean it up? or you think there is a way to combine them together?

Comment: Oh, I thought it was already a file that you needed to edit. If it's a string go with mjolinor's answer, it will suit your needs wonderfully. RegEx is a wonderful tool for a situation like this. My solution really does work best for an array, like a file would be read in as. A multiline string is better suited for the Replace operator.